# Windows driver C1083 error

Tags: c, driver, device-driver, wdk

I created simple "Hello world" windows driver.

**hello.c**

```
#include <ntddk.h> 

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) 
{
    DbgPrint("Hello, World\n");
    return STATUS_SUCCESS; 
}
```

**makefile**

```
!INCLUDE $(NTMAKEENV)\makefile.def
```

**sources**

```
TARGETNAME = hello
TARGETPATH = obj
TARGETTYPE = DRIVER

INCLUDES   = %BUILD%\inc
LIBS       = %BUILD%\lib

SOURCES    = hello.c
```

If I build driver by Checked Build Environment, I get:

> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h': No such file or directory

`sourceannotations.h` is included in `C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\crt` and `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\CodeAnalysis`, but I can only use included files from Winddk directory.

Do you have any suggestion what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I incorrectly installed the DDK, because after reinstalling DDK I compiled files without problems.